# Imprimir un par de caracteres sin repetir

Tags: c

Lo que debo hacer es almacenar en una matrix un par de carácteres seleccionado aleatoriamente y imprimirlo así.

```
? # ¡ x
x ? # ¡
0 - + *
+ 0 - *
```

El problema es que no encuentro una forma de marcar los caracteres que han salido dos veces, para no incluirlos más.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char a[4][4];
char cartas[]={'#','%','@','0','*','!','<','x'};
int total=sizeof(cartas);

int main()
{
   srand(time(0));

   for (int i=0;i<4;i++)
   {
       for (int j=0;j<4;j++)
       {
           a[i][j]=cartas[rand()%total];
           printf("\t%c",a[i][j]);
       }
     printf("\n\n");
   }
}
```

Alguien conoce alguna forma?

Comment: cada vez que seleccionas `cartas[rand()%total];` miras en un array temporal. Si ese array temporal tiene menos de 2 elementos de ese tipo, lo metes en el array en la matriz `a` y lo imprimes. Con un while encuentras un elemento que no esté 2 veces dentro

Comment: tambien podrias ir contando la cantidad de veces que aparecio cada caracter, y si ya aparecio dos veces no usarlo. hay tantas formas de hacer esto... igual cuidado porque las ultimas iteraciones podrian ser eternas si el random no le pega a los caracteres que te faltan...

Comment: El problema con eso que si el carácter seleccionado ya ha salido dos veces no imprimes nada debes imprimir el cuadro 4x4 completamente

Comment: @cheroky que? cual es tu consulta puntual, se te acaban de dar un par de ideas.

Comment: Con 4x4 iteraciones sin usar un bucle extra se ocurre ir removiendo los elementos que ya han salido dos veces

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yo empezaría por inicializar la matriz del juego. No es vital pero sí importante:

```
char a[4][4] = {'\0'};
```

Después prepararía el array para poder iterar facilmente por el. Lo más sencillo es linealizar el array para trabajar sobre una dimensión. No hay problema porque `a[4][4]` reserva 16 posiciones de memoria consecutivas:

```
char* ptr = (char*)a;
```

Ahora se rellena el array. Para no complicar las cosas lo rellenamos por orden: primero dos copias de la primera carta, después dos copias de la segunda...

```
for (i=0;i<16;i+=2)
{
  ptr[i]   = cartas[i/2];
  ptr[i+1] = cartas[i/2];
}
```

Ahora se barajan las cartas. Para ello se itera una vez el array y, para cada posición, se elige otra posición al azar con la que intercambiar sus cartas:

```
for( i=0; i<16; i++ )
{
  j = i;
  while( j == i ) j = rand()%16;

  char temp = ptr[i];
  ptr[i] = ptr[j];
  ptr[j] = temp;
}
```

Este barrido se podría hacer dos o más veces.

Y ya está, todas las cartas mezcladas, como se puede comprobar con un bucle final:

```
for(  i=0; i<4; i++ )
{
  for(  j=0; j<4; j++ )
    printf("%c ",a[i][j]);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: No veo el sentido del uso de while y la asignación j = i

Comment: @cheroky si por azar `j==i` entonces no se va a realizar ninguna permutación. De ahí el bucle, para garantizar que las cartas se mezclan. La asignación es porque un `do-while` queda más feo